# mysql select and update using one query in this case?

Tags: mysql

Can I select and update together? Instead of use 2 queries, can I use just one?

```
SELECT data FROM log limit 1

update log SET `data` = $now where `id` = 1
```

any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What would be the result of such operation?

Comment: @KamilG. I want to allow just one user to read this date, the first one who opens the page and this first user should update the date. a function will be avaliable each 5 minutes, can't be avaliable for 2 users at the same time. This way, select and update together in a MyISAM engine I can do what I want, can't i?

Comment: You can't do `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in one query. Use a transaction to prevent someone else from changing the database between the queries.

Comment: Transactions don't work in MyISAM, so use `LOCK TABLE data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock the table to prevent another user from updating the table.

```
LOCK TABLES data;
SELECT data FROM log WHERE id = 1;
// fetch the result
UPDATE log SET data = NOW() WHERE id = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```