# MySQL Update activity when selecting user details

Tags: php, mysql

Table:

userid, sessionid, last_active

I got the following requests:

```
SELECT `userid` FROM `session_keys` WHERE `sessionid`='SESSION_ID'

UPDATE `session_keys` SET `last_active`=now() WHERE `sessionid`='SESSION_ID'
```

Is it possible to put it in one request? but I need the callback from the select request.

The only goal i wanna reach is to update the last_active time of an timestamp when selecting the data.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, but I'm unclear what your exact request is.

Comment: You could put both statements inside a transaction so they're grouped and succeed or fail together. But generally SQL statements execute one at a time. What's the reason for wanting to group/combine the statements, out of curiosity?

Comment: I wanna update the last active time automatically when selecting the data...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SET @session_id = 'SESSION_ID';
SELECT `userid` INTO @sid FROM `session_keys` WHERE `sessionid` = @session_id;
UPDATE `session_keys` SET `last_active`=now() WHERE `sessionid` = @session_id;
SELECT @sid;
```

Could you give more context?

Comment: The only goal i wanna reach is to update the last_active time of an timestamp when selecting the data.

Comment: Do you want to do it by running the code from PHP or MySQL?

Comment: mysql prefered.

Comment: did you try the queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
UPDATE
    'tableA' AS 'A',
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            'tableB'
        WHERE
            'id' = x
    ) AS 'src'
SET
    'A'.'col1' = 'src'.'col1'
WHERE
    'A'.'id' = x
;
```

Comment: I cannot understand what it does :o

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful:

[Select and Update in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583747/select-and-update-in-same-query) (I know that you have the same table in both queries)

[mysql select and update using one query in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562867/mysql-select-and-update-using-one-query-in-this-case)